# as3 + red5/fms: recording audio from soundmixer

Tags: actionscript-3, red5, audio-recording, flash-media-server

i'm wondering if there's a way to record live audio from flash' SoundMixer (NOT from the microphone).

Might be a simple question but i'm a noob with red5/fms technologies and can't find anything online that answers my question :\

TIA for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot involved in getting this all working, but the core of the solution is to configure your Flash app to:

1. Create a `NetConnection` object
2. Create a `NetStream` object, passing the `NetConnection` to the constructor
3. Call your `NetStream` object's `attachAudio` method, passing it an instance of whatever audio source you want to use.
4. When you want to stop recording, simply close the `NetStream` object.

in code, that would look something like:

```
private var myMic:Microphone;
private var nc:NetConnection;
private var ns:NetStream;

// get connected
private function get_connected():void {
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect("rtmp://your.domain.tld:1935");
}


// get audio source
private function init_audio():void {
    myMic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
}

// start recording
private function start_recording(fileName:String):void {
    ns = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.attachAudio(myMic);
    ns.publish(fileName, "record");
}

// stop recording
private function stop recording():void {
    ns.play(false); // flushes the recording buffer
    ns.close();
}
```

I realize that's a pretty broad overview, but it's a pretty broad topic. Please comment if you have questions on the specifics.